# Opening a intent:// link from a WebView

Tags: android, android-webview, nativescript

This is written in NativeScript (Javascript), but it is directly taken from an android solution I found here on SO for opening different url schemes in a android WebView.

However, I believe the solution I found was to open for example `fb://`, `me://` `tel://` etc, and not `intent://` links.

```
web.android.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

let webViewClient = android.webkit.WebViewClient.extend({
    shouldOverrideUrlLoading : function(view, url){

        if( url.getUrl().getScheme().indexOf('http') != -1 ){
            return false;
        }

        // Otherwise allow the OS to handle things like tel, mailto, etc.
        let intent = new android.content.Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, android.net.Uri.parse(url.getUrl()));
        application.android.currentContext.startActivity( intent );
        return true;                    
    }
})

web.android.setWebChromeClient(new android.webkit.WebChromeClient());
web.android.setWebViewClient(new webViewClient());

web.android.loadUrl("https://example.com");
```

My application listens to an intent opening it, and acts on the parameters served to it. The app is usually opened via the mobiles browser, when someone clicks on a specific button on the website. This works as normal.

However, I have an WebView in the application which leads to the website. When I first tried clicking the button here, I got the following error `net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME`

With the above solution, the app just suddenly stops working, and I get a question to restart the app.

If I change the following line from:

```
let intent = new android.content.Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, android.net.Uri.parse(url.getUrl()));
```

to:

```
let intent = new android.content.Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, url.getUrl());
```

I get the following error: `No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=intent://user/random launchParam=MultiScreenLaunchParams....}`

Anyone with a tip? Thanks.

Comment: how did u fix this issue, m also facing similar issue?

Comment: @VenkatBallem Sorry, I no longer have access to the repository for that project. But I do remember having issues with this when the app was open in the background vs when it was completely shut down. If thats any help.